# Почему метод append() с каждым разом добавляет на 1 тег больше?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть скрипт который добавляет строку в самый конец таблицы перед тегом `</tbody>`

```
$(function () {
  $('.addrowreg').click(function () {
    $('.popup,.popup_overlay').fadeIn(400); //показываем всплывающее окно

    $('.closer,.popup_overlay').click(function(){
      $('.popup,.popup_overlay').fadeOut(400); //скрываем всплывающее окно
    });
    $('#addreg').click(function () {
      var valreg = $('#regname').val();
      var newreg = '<tr><td colspan="4" id="rhdr" style="text-align: center;" class="editor"><strong>'+valreg+'</strong></td><td><input class="addaddress" type="button" value="+"/></td></tr>';
      $('tbody').append(newreg);
      $('.popup,.popup_overlay').fadeOut(400);
    });
  });
});


<table cellpadding="15" cellspacing="0" id="of_ad" style="width: 100%;">
<tbody>
    <tr class="table_head">
        <td nowrap="nowrap" style="text-align: left;">
            Округ / Город</td>
        <td nowrap="nowrap" style="text-align: left;">
            Городской номер</td>
        <td  style="text-align: left;">
            Внутренний номер</td>    
        <td style="text-align: left;">
            Адрес</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="region">
        <td colspan="4" id="rhdr" style="text-align: center;">
            <strong>Волга</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="active">
        <td class="editor">Самара</td>
        <td class="editor">7-111-2450105</td>
        <td class="editor">319</td>    
        <td class="editor">443081, Г. Самара,Ул. Ленина, дом 27, 8 этаж, офис 100</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
```

Проблема в том что после нажатия на элемент `#addreg`, происходит добавление одной строки `<tr>`. После второго нажатия добавляется стразу 2 строки, после третьего сразу 3, и.т.д 
Почему так происходит?
Как добиться добавления только одного элемента?

Comment: Приведите [mcve], потому что с этим кодом всё в порядке

Comment: @andreymal добавил, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: Ну вот теперь стало очевидно, что вы вешаете второй, третий, четвёртый и так далее обработчики клика `#addreg` каждый раз, когда вы кликаете на `.addrowreg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте изменить ваш `js` следующим образом:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.closer,.popup_overlay').click(function(){
    $('.popup,.popup_overlay').fadeOut(400); //скрываем всплывающее окно
  });
  $('#addreg').click(function () {
    var valreg = $('#regname').val();
    var newreg = '<tr><td colspan="4" id="rhdr" style="text-align: center;" class="editor"><strong>'+valreg+'</strong></td><td><input class="addaddress" type="button" value="+"/></td></tr>';
    $('tbody').append(newreg);
    $('.popup,.popup_overlay').fadeOut(400);
  });
  $('.addrowreg').click(function () {
    $('.popup,.popup_overlay').fadeIn(400);
  });
})
```

Источник проблемы:
Когда вы добавляете обработчик клика на `.addrowreg`, вы также каждый раз добавляете ещё один обработчик клика на элемент `#addreg`, что соответственно приводит к тому, что с каждым последующим разом вызывается на 1 обработчик больше, и строки добавляются инкрементно.

Важный урок:
Не добавляется обработчики события в другом обработчике события.